# Reasoning about combinations of distinct modular classes of $5$ and $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, combinations

Let $S = \{ x \in \ Z\, | \, 1 \le x \le 35\}$

For integers $a,b,c,d$ with $0 \le a < b < 5$ and $0 \le c < d < 7$, let:

$$C_{a,b,c,d} = \{ x \in S\,|\, x \not\equiv a \pmod 5,\, x \not\equiv b \pmod 5,\, x \not\equiv c \pmod 7,\, x \not\equiv d \pmod 7 \,\}$$

There are ${ 7 \choose 2 } \times { 5 \choose 2 } = 210$ such distinct sets $C_{a,b,c,d}$

For any $1 \le x \le 34$, there are:

- ${ 6 \choose 2} \times {4 \choose 2} =90$ distinct sets $C_{a,b,c,d}$ where $x \in C_{a,b,c,d}$
- $210 - 90 = 120$ distinct sets $C_{a,b,c,d}$ where $x \not\in C_{a,b,c,d}$
- ${ 5 \choose 2} \times { 3 \choose 2} = 30$ distinct sets $C_{a,b,c,d}$ where $x \in C_{a,b,c,d}$ and $(x+1) \in C_{a,b,c,d}$

Here's my question.  I am unclear about how to handle this case:

> How many distinct sets $C_{a,b,c,d}$ such that $x \not\in C_{a,b,c,d}$ and $(x+1) \not\in C_{a,b,c,d}$?

I am hoping that someone can help me to understand how to count this number of distinct sets.

---

Edit:

I have restated my question based on Quasi's feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be more convenient to work mod $35$. The counts will be the same.

Applying that change, let

- $Z_{35}=\{0,...,34\}$.$\\[4pt]$

  $Z_{5}=\{0,...,4\}$.$\\[4pt]$

  $Z_{7}=\{0,...,6\}$.

For $a,b\in Z_5$ with $0\le a < b$, and $c,d\in Z_7$ with $0\le c < d$, let
$$
C_{a,b,c,d} = \{
x \in Z_{35}\mid 
x \not\equiv a,b\;(\text{mod}\;5),
x \not\equiv c,d\;(\text{mod}\;7)
\}
$$
**Claim:**$\;$For all $x\in Z_{35}$, there are exactly $60$ sets $C_{a,b,c,d}$ such that $x,x+1\not\in C_{a,b,c,d}$.

Consider the complementary count . . .

Let $x\in Z_{35}$.

- There are exactly $90$ sets $C_{a,b,c,d}$ such that $x\in C_{a,b,c,d}$.$\\[4pt]$

  There are exactly $90$ sets $C_{a,b,c,d}$ such that $x+1\in C_{a,b,c,d}$.$\\[4pt]$

  There are exactly $30$ sets $C_{a,b,c,d}$ such that $x,x+1\in C_{a,b,c,d}$.

hence there are $90+90-30=150$ sets $C_{a,b,c,d}$ such that at least one of $x,x+1$ is in $C_{a,b,c,d}$.

Since there are a total of $210$ distinct sets $C_{a,b,c,d}$, it follows that there are exactly $210-150=60$ sets $C_{a,b,c,d}$ such that $x,x+1\not\in C_{a,b,c,d}$.

Comment: Awesome!  I suspected that there was a straight forward answer!  Thanks very much!  :-)